# Find Intersection Between Date Ranges In PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have records with a two dates `check_in` and `check_out`, I want to know the ranges when more than one person was checked in at the same time.

So if I have the following checkin / checkouts:

- Person A: `1PM - 6PM`
- Person B: `3PM - 10PM`
- Person C: `9PM - 11PM`

I would want to get `3PM - 6PM` (Overlap of person A and B) and `9PM - 10PM` (overlap of person B and C).

I can write an algorithm to do this in linear time with code, is it possible to do this via a relational query in linear time with `PostgreSQL` as well?

It needs to have a minimal response, meaning no overlapping ranges. So if there were a result which gave the range `6PM - 9PM` and `8PM - 10PM` it would be incorrect. It should instead return `6PM - 10pm`.

Comment: Your Postgres version, your exact table definition (complete `CREATE TABLE` script including all constraints or what you get with `\d tbl` in psql) and some sample data would be nice to have.

Comment: yes, version would help us answer, recent releases have added new date range features which may be applicable.

Comment: I imagine the solution will involve window functions and possibly recursive CTEs

Answer (score 3):

#### Assumptions

The solution heavily depends on the exact table definition including all constraints. For lack of information in the question I'll assume this table:

```
CREATE TABLE booking (
  booking_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, check_in   timestamptz NOT NULL
, check_out  timestamptz NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT valid_range CHECK (check_out > check_in)
);
```

So, no NULL values, only valid ranges with inclusive lower and exclusive upper bound, and we don't really care *who* checks in.

Also assuming a current version of Postgres, at least **9.2**.

#### Query

One way to do it with only SQL using a `UNION ALL` and window functions:

```
SELECT ts AS check_id, next_ts As check_out
FROM  (
   SELECT *, lead(ts) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS next_ts
   FROM  (
      SELECT *, lag(people_ct, 1 , 0) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS prev_ct
      FROM  (
         SELECT ts, sum(sum(change)) OVER (ORDER BY ts)::int AS people_ct
         FROM  (
            SELECT check_in AS ts, 1 AS change FROM booking
            UNION ALL
            SELECT check_out, -1 FROM booking
            ) sub1
         GROUP  BY 1
         ) sub2
      ) sub3
   WHERE  people_ct > 1 AND prev_ct < 2 OR  -- start overlap
          people_ct < 2 AND prev_ct > 1     -- end overlap
   ) sub4
WHERE  people_ct > 1 AND prev_ct < 2;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/02efb/1)

#### Explanation

- In subquery `sub1` derive a table of `check_in` and `check_out` in one column. `check_in` adds one to the crowd, `check_out` subtracts one.
- In `sub2` sum all events for the same point in time and compute a running count with a window function: that's the window function `sum()` over an aggregate `sum()` -  and cast to `integer` or we get `numeric` from this:

  ```
     sum(sum(change)) OVER (ORDER BY ts)::int
  ```
- In `sub3` look at the count of the previous row
- In `sub4` only keep rows where overlapping time ranges start and end, and pull the end of the time range into the same row with `lead()`.
- Finally, only keep rows, where time ranges start.

---

To *optimize performance* I would walk through the table *once* in a plpgsql function like demonstrated in this related answer on dba.SE:

- [Calculate Difference in Overlapping Time in PostgreSQL / SSRS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/111946/3684)

Answer (score 1):

Idea is to divide time in periods and save them as bit values with specified granularity.

- `0` - nobody is checked in one grain
- `1` - somebody is checked in one grain

Let's assume that granularity is 1 hour and period is 1 day.

- 000000000000000000000000 means nobody is checked in that day
- 000000000000000000000110 means somebody is checked between 21 and 23
- 000000000000011111000000 means somebody is checked between 13 and 18
- 000000000000000111111100 means somebody is checked between 15 and 22

After that we do binary OR on the each value in the range and we have our answer.

- 000000000000011111111110

It can be done in linear time. Here is an example from Oracle but it can be transformed to PostgreSQL easily.

```
with rec (checkin, checkout)
as ( select 13, 18 from dual 
   union all 
    select 15, 22 from dual 
   union all 
    select 21, 23 from dual )
,spanempty ( empt)
 as ( select '000000000000000000000000' from dual) ,
 spanfull( full)
 as ( select '111111111111111111111111' from dual)
, bookingbin( binbook) as ( select  substr(empt, 1, checkin) || 
        substr(full, checkin, checkout-checkin) || 
        substr(empt, checkout, 24-checkout) 
 from rec 
 cross join spanempty
 cross join spanfull ),
 bookingInt (rn, intbook) as 
 ( select rownum, bin2dec(binbook) from bookingbin),
 bitAndSum (bitAndSumm) as (
 select sum(bitand(b1.intbook, b2.intbook)) from bookingInt b1 
 join bookingInt b2 
 on b1.rn = b2.rn -1 ) ,
 SumAll (sumall) as (
 select sum(bin2dec(binbook)) from bookingBin  )
select lpad(dec2bin(sumall - bitAndSumm), 24, '0')
from SumAll, bitAndSum
```

Result:

```
000000000000011111111110
```